# VB.Net Iterate through two listboxes

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to iterate through two listboxes and adding all the items to one list.
Here's my code so far but I can't seem to integrate the second listbox into it.

```
Dim List As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
For Each LB1 As String In Listbox1.Items
     List.Add(vbTab + vbTab + "ent = maps\mp\_utility::createOneshotEffect(" + """" + LB1.ToString() + """" + ");" + vbCrLf +
     vbTab + vbTab + "ent.v[ " + """" + "origin" + """" + " ] = ( " + LB2.ToString() + " );"
Next
```

Comment: just do the same thing again but with ListBox2

Comment: Then my List wont be setup right.

Comment: Please don't use `Chr()` unless you have to. For `Chr(9)` use `vbTab` and for `Chr(34)` use `""` (double quote character escapes the quote character). This is way more readable.

Comment: I should have posted more info about how I wanted the list be, sorry about that. But tgolisch posted exactly what I needed so the question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as LB1 and LB2 both contain the same number of items and both are ordered the same, you could use an indexed loop (instead of a foreach loop):

```
Dim List As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

For x as integer = 0 to Listbox1.Items.count - 1
    List.Add(vbTab + vbTab + "ent = maps\mp\_utility::createOneshotEffect(""" + _
        ListBox1.Items(x).ToString() + """);" + vbCrLf + _
        vbTab + vbTab + "ent.v[ ""origin"" ] = ( " + _
        ListBox2.Items(x).ToString() + " );" _
    )
Next
```